# Adding Items to a binded ASP.NET Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Is there any possibilities for adding rows to an already binded listview ?
I tried this; But not working

```
        ListViewDataItem lid = new ListViewDataItem(ListView3.Items.Count+1, ListView3.Items.Count+1);
        ListView3.Items.Add(lid);
```

If It's not possible, Where can I store the rows added from the client ?

Comment: You can add rows to data source e.g the DataTable before binding to ListView

Comment: @Adil But In ASP.NET, where can I store the DataTable ?

Comment: How you bind datasource to ListView, you can fill datatable with database records using SqlDataAdapter

Comment: Yes Iam using DataAdapter. But I want to let the users to add theirs rows too. But I will lose the DataTable after the page is served to the client right ?

Comment: I did this,., I read all the values from Listview to a Datatable, when I need to add a row. Then I inserted my new record. Then binding the listview again..